# Joint and marginal distributions of independent uniformly distributed variables

Tags: probability-distributions

> Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independently uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1). Find the joint and marginal distributions of $U=X_1X_2$ and $V=X_1/X_2$.

I think that $f_U(u) = \int^1_0f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(u/x_1){1\over{|x_1|}} dx_1$

I'm not sure if that is right. If it is right, would the marginal distribution just be $\int^1_0 X_1X_2 dx_1$ and $\int^1_0 X_1X_2 dx_2$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **HINT :** $$
X_1=\sqrt{UV}\quad\text{ and }\quad X_2=\sqrt{\frac{U}{V}},
$$
then you find the Jacobian.

Comment: Thanks, I found the Jacobian to be $-{\sqrt {U/V}}\over 2\sqrt{UV}$ is that right?

Comment: Yep, it's almost correct but you can simplify that into $\dfrac{1}{2V}$ and Jacobian is always positive. Now, you obtain the regions of $U$ and $V$ based on the regions of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: $0<UV<1$ and $0<U/V<1$, so $0<U<V$?

Comment: Yep! That's correct. Now, try to plot them and integrate it carefully. Here is the plot I made using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+0%3Cuv%3C1+and+0%3Cu%2Fv%3C1).

Comment: You should consider the region in the first quadrant only, the positive part because the support of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is positive.

Comment: so are the integrals i'm looking for $\int 2V dv$ and $\int 2V du$? If so, how do I work out the bounds?

Comment: You forgot to vote up my answer. :)

Comment: Great, thanks. I got a little bit muddled up but now I get the right answer too.

Comment: I tried but I need 5 more reputation!

Comment: I give you 5 reputations.

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy :D

Comment: Yeah, anyway you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint PDF of $U$ and $V$ is
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\cdot|J|=\frac1{2v}.
$$
Now for the regions. You have $0\le x_1\le1$, this region is corresponding to 
$$0\le \sqrt{uv}\le1\;\Rightarrow\;0\le uv\le 1\;\Rightarrow\;0\le v\le \frac1u.$$ 
It's due to $X_1=\sqrt{UV}$. You also have $0\le x_2\le1$, this region is corresponding to 
$$0\le \sqrt{\dfrac uv}\le1\;\Rightarrow\;0\le \dfrac uv\le1\;\Rightarrow\;0\le u\le v.$$
It's due to your transformation $X_2=\sqrt{\dfrac UV}$. If you plot those regions (check the plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+0%3Cuv%3C1+and+0%3Cu%2Fv%3C1)), you can obtain the marginal PDFs of $U$ and $V$ as follow
$$
\begin{align}
f_U(u)&=\int_{v=u}^{\frac1u}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ dv\ ;\quad\text{the region is bounded by $v=u$ and $v=\frac1u$ if you see it from $u$-axis}\\
&=\int_{v=u}^{\frac1u}\frac1{2v}\ dv\\
&=\left.\frac 12\ln v\right|_{v=u}^{\frac1u}\\
&=\frac 12\ln \left(\frac1u\right)-\frac 12\ln u\\
&=-\ln u\;;\quad\text{ for } 0\le u\le1.
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
f_V(v)&=\int_{u=0}^{v}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ du\ ;\quad\text{the region is bounded by $u=0$ and $u=v$ if you see it from $v$-axis}\\
&=\int_{u=0}^{v}\frac1{2v}\ du\\
&=\left.\frac u{2v}\right|_{u=0}^{v}\\
&=\frac12\;;\quad\text{ for } 0\le v\le1,
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
f_V(v)&=\int_{u=0}^{\frac1v}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ du\ ;\quad\text{the region is bounded by $u=0$ and $u=\frac1v$ if you see it from $v$-axis}\\
&=\int_{u=0}^{\frac1v}\frac1{2v}\ du\\
&=\left.\frac u{2v}\right|_{u=0}^{\frac1v}\\
&=\frac 1{2v^2}\;;\quad\text{ for } 1\le v\le\infty.
\end{align}
$$
It can also be written as
$$
f_V(v)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l l}
\frac12&\;;\quad\text{ for } 0\le v\le1,\\\\
\frac 1{2v^2}&\;;\quad\text{ for } 1\le v\le\infty.
  \end{array} \right.
$$